# Quiz: Count Unique Words 'Udacity'

Tags: python, data-structures

I have a task to find the number of unique words in the text below.

There's three parts to the quiz

1. Split verse into a list of words. Hint: You can use a string method you learned in the previous lesson.
2. Convert the list into a data structure that would keep only the unique elements from the list.
3. Print the length of the container.

I have attempted to split the verse into a list. By doing the following:

```
verse = [
["if you can keep your head when all about you are losing theirs and blaming it on you"],
["if you can trust yourself when all men doubt you"],
["but make allowance for their doubting too"],
["if you can wait and not be tired by waiting"],
["or being lied about  don’t deal in lies"],
["or being hated"],
["don’t give way to hating"],
["and yet don’t look too good"],
["nor talk too wise"]]
print(verse, '\n')
```

This is the second part of the question:

```
# split verse into list of words
verse_list = str.split(str="", num=string.count(str))
print(verse_list, '\n')

# convert list to a data structure that stores unique elements
verse_set = ''.join(array) 
print(verse_set, '\n')

# print the number of unique words
num_unique = verse.len 
print(num_unique, '\n')
```

When I run test I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vm_main3.py", line 47, in <module>
    import main
  File "/tmp/vmuser_gbztlklphw/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import studentMain
  File "/tmp/vmuser_gbztlklphw/studentMain.py", line 1, in <module>
    import count_unique_words
  File "/tmp/vmuser_gbztlklphw/count_unique_words.py", line 14, in <module>
    verse_list = str.split(str="", num=string.count(str))
NameError: name 'string' is not defined
[['if you can keep your head when all about you are losing theirs and blaming it on you'], ['if you can trust yourself when all men doubt you'], ['but make allowance for their doubting too'], ['if you can wait and not be tired by waiting'], ['or being lied about  don’t deal in lies'], ['or being hated'], ['don’t give way to hating'], ['and yet don’t look too good'], ['nor talk too wise']]
```

If someone can please explain to me what I am doing wrong and how I can go about answering the questions correctly that would be great.

Comment: error shows you that you use `string` which doesn't exists. It also shows you in which line you use this `string`. So why do you use `string` ? What do you try to achieve with this `string` ?

Comment: I don't know why you use this `string` because to split you need only `.split(" ")`

Comment: BTW: if somewhere is said "use a string method" then it may mean that you have to use literally string - `"some text".function()` - not necessarily module `string`  - `string.function()`.

Comment: did you get verse as single string or list of lists with sentence in every sublist ? If you get as single string then you can use `verse.split()` to get list with all words. And then you can convert to `set()` to get unique words. And then you can count it with `len()`

Answer (score 2):

You didn't show what `verse` was originally. I'm guessing it's a long string, something like this:

```
verse = "if you can keep your head when " \
        "all about you are losing theirs " \
        "and blaming it on you " \
        "if you can trust yourself when all " \
        "men doubt you " \
        "but make allowance for their doubting too " \
        "if you can wait and not be tired by waiting " \
        "or being lied about  don’t deal in lies " \
        "or being hated don’t give way to hating " \
        "and yet don’t look too good nor talk too wise"
```

The instructions say:

> Split verse into a list of words

They go on to say that you can use a string method to do this for you. You did not do this. You hardcoded a list of lists of strings, and then bound that to the variable `verse`. You are not using the string method. You also didn't actually hardcode the thing the instructions asked for: They want a list of words. That means one list, where each element is a word.

Simply do this:

```
words = verse.split()
```

There's your list of words.

Next the instructions say:

> Convert the list into a data structure that would keep only the unique
>   elements from the list.

By that they mean a set.

```
unique_words = set(words)
```

And finally:

> Print the length of the container.

```
print(f"The number of unique words is: {len(unique_words)}")
```